# Clip Studio Paint Assets download on Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, linux-mint, xdgutils

Ok so I installed Clip Studio Paint a few weeks ago on Linux Mint using PlayOnLinux and everything has been working great but for some reason, I can't download Assets, not from the application itself or through the website https://assets.clip-studio.com/ which is my main issue. I click on the download button and xdg-open is called to open the downloaded Asset using the application but as I click open nothing happens. This is what happens on Google Chrome, on Firefox I get this notice:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWwsd.png)

I'm not sure if Clip Studio isn't launched because it's running through PlayOnLinux or because it's Linux in general. Is there a way to get around this? Either download the asset as a normal file through a script or configure xdg-open to open Clip Studio or something else?

Comment: Have you tried looking on forums about (or the developers of) Clip Studio? StackOverflow is for development related questions. This seems off topic for the site.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.